# Upgrading Wireshark

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, wireshark

I have 16.04 LTS loaded. The distribution came with Wireshark ver 2.2.6. Wireshark now has available version 2.4.5. I downloaded the executable, but don't know how to upgrade my system to the new version. I tried removing and installing, but Ubuntu just loads 2.2.6 again. I am relatively new to Linux. How is this done? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Add the PPA to your system

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wireshark-dev/stable
```

Update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install

```
sudo apt-get install wireshark
```

You should have the latest stable version 2.6.1 of Wireshark installed

Reference: [Wireshark on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~wireshark-dev/+archive/ubuntu/stable)